# Excel VBA - Extract info from different worksheet with filtered datas

Tags: vba, excel

I will need help to create a macro for excel that can extract data from sheet 2 and generate the data in sheet 1 for a specific field (Eg. cell B14). I will need this data to be generated by clicking the command button.

Also, the data i need from sheet 2 is in a long list and i need to filter the datas (Eg. Countries) to retrieve result only for 1 particular country.